# Array element outside function is undefined with Android 5.1

Tags: javascript, android, arrays, cordova, associative-array

I have a cordova application with some JavaScript code:

```
function test(){
   a = new Array();
   a['var_a']=5;
   a['var_b']=10;

   return a;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    return_arr = test();

    console.log(return_arr['var_a']);
});
```

My expected result is `5`. In Intel XDK Emulator and with my Blackberry with OS 10 I also get `5`. However with a Cubot phone with Android 5.1 I receive `undefined`.

What could lead to this different behavior?
My solution is to make the return_arr global, but I am still interested in why my code should be wrong?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are indexed, whereas you are looking for properties.  You would be better using an object, rather than an array...

```
function test(){
   a = {};  // declare an empty object
   a['var_a']=5;
   a['var_b']=10;

   return a;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    return_arr = test();

    console.log(return_arr['var_a']);
});
```

Comment: Yes I know that an object might be the better one. However the associative array works in some environment, but not on the Cubot phone. Why?

Comment: My question would be more about why it works in any environment, not why it doesn't in some.  It shouldn't work at all.  My answer was posted as an alternative to your suggestion of making the array global.  Other than that being a bodge to just "make it work", it also shouldn't change anything!  That code returns an empty array in both IE and Chrome, so I would simply just stop going down that route at all.

Comment: Ah, you checked in several Browsers and it is a browser issue? So thanks! I will try it.

Comment: No problem - happy to help.  Good luck :)